# my href link isn't working with my button in my html document

Tags: html

so basically I have this button that doesn't work, when I hover over it my cursor doesn't change and when I click it nothing happens, here's the buttons line of code:

```
<button href="dwr.php" class="dwrbutton fas fa-address-card"> <div class="dwrtext">DWR</div></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Href is not a button attribute.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp

Use a form with the link as action, or try a <A> tag with styling

Answer (score 0):

add button class to anchor tag

```
<a href="dwr.php" class="btn btn-info"><div class="dwrtext">DWR</div></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set a href on your button simply wrap it with an [anchor element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a).

Your code should look something like this:

```html
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/"><button href="dwr.php" class="dwrbutton fas fa-address-card">DWR</button></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use the `button`-tag, then you should look [*here*](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/html/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link.html) for a solution to your problem. Especially preferred if you need the `button`-tag within a form.

If you don't care how the link is implemented, then I would personally use an `a`-tag, which you can then design according to your preferences, also like a button.

Have fun and good luck!